# I can't add this font and I don't understand what's causing the issue I'm having

Tags: r

So, I've come to you guys for assistance because I don't know what I'm doing

Here's what I have going on:

`library(extrafont)`

```
download.file("http://simonsoftware.se/other/xkcd.ttf",
              dest="xkcd.ttf", mode="wb")
system("mkdir ~/.fonts")
system("cp xkcd.ttf  ~/.fonts")
font_import(paths = "~/.fonts", pattern="[X/x]kcd")
fonts()
loadfonts()
```

Except the issue is, when I get to `system("mkdir ~/.fonts")` I get this error:

> /Rtools/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory '~/.fonts': No such file or directory
>   [1] 1

How do I heckin' make this stop doing that? I just wanna make a graph with someone's ugly handwriting.

Comment: Hard to tell what is happening from the information that you've provided. But it sounds as though you may lack the privileges required to create the directory -- or perhaps you're running Windows, which doesn't understand `~` in file paths. If the latter issue is the one affecting you, just try `dir.create("~/.fonts")` instead of `system("mkdir ~/.fonts")`.

Comment: You were such a big help! Yes, it was because I was running Windows! This actually completely fixed the whole thing. You're the best thank you so much!